# Hijack `repaint()` call in Java Swing component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing an app which runs in a headless environment and needs to output to a `BufferedImage` instead of a screen. I have a `Display` class managing the `BufferedImage`. My app extends `JPanel` and in order to make it automatically repaint when a component updates, I've re-implemented `repaint()` as:

```
public void repaint(){
    Graphics2D g = getDisplay().getGraphics();
    paint(g);
    getDisplay().repaint();
}
```

Whenever I start up my app, though, I get a `NullPointerException` when it tries to draw to the `Display`. This is supposedly some code in the `JPanel` constructor that tries to repaint. The problem is that `getDisplay()` returns null. However, *the `Display` has already been instantiated and passed to the app at this point.* I've verified this by having the `Display` print out its own properties on creation, before sending it to the app.

The exception is as follows; the topmost location refers to the line containing `getDisplay()`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mypapyri.clay.ui.App.repaint(App.java:28)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setFont(JComponent.java:2746)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(LookAndFeel.java:208)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(BasicPanelUI.java:66)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:56)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:655)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
    at com.mypapyri.clay.ui.App.<init>(App.java:18)
    at ClayOS.<init>(ClayOS.java:22)
    at ClayOS.main(ClayOS.java:84)
```

**EDIT:** I've researched this and could not find a satisfactory resolution.

- [The repaint() method and the GUI thread](http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/mes/courses/cps530/programs/threads/Repaint/index.html)
- Javadocs for [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)
- PaintManager and RepaintManager

Comment: Sorry, but which class does `com.mypapyri.clay.ui.App` extends?

Comment: Extends `JPanel` (see first paragraph).

Comment: I just can't find method `getDisplay()` for `JPanel` in [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html). What am i doing wrong?)

Comment: Perhaps it is a method the OP wrote? @nidu

Comment: `getDisplay()` is a custom method my extended class implements. Basically, I'm passing the `Display` in the `App` constructor, and then `repaint()` uses this to draw.

Comment: It seems that `repaint()` method is called before your `App` constructor code. When `App` constructor is called - at first all extended constructors are called and one of the constructors calls `repaint()` (after `javax.swing.JComponent.setFont(JComponent.java:2746)`). Look at the stack trace. I suppose you should just add a `null` value check to avoid this case.

Comment: Do you call super() in the constructor? It seems that the JPanel (not yours) constructor is calling repaint before you set the display

Comment: That was it! I changed the display to static and set it before the constructor. If you propose this as a solution I'll accept it. I'm having other issues now but I'll post another question.

Comment: See also [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nidu told it first, but since he doesn't answer I put it.

Probably you're calling super() in the constructor method, and the JPanel constructor is trying to repaint before the display has been set.